# How can I write a unit test using jest, react, testing-library for this component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to write unit tests using Jest and testing-library in a React typescript project. And how can I create an ID for my component ErrorModal to use in my test? I never wrote a test before!! Thank you.

```
const ErrorModal = (props: {message: string}) => {

  const { message } = props;

  return (
    <ErrorModalStyled>
      <ErrorMessageStyled>{ message }</ErrorMessageStyled>
    </ErrorModalStyled>
  );
}

export default ErrorModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a little bit about jest.

In your case, try this.
https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react#dom-testing

Basically, you will test if "message" is actually being rendered in your component by querying it.

Comment: I just can't do it alone, just don't know how DD: i need an example for this one please. i have others components to test. just one example it will help me a lot

Comment: can you help me please?